# Android endless activity loop

Tags: android, performance, android-activity, overriding, ondestroy

Hello I have a small problem which kinda acts like a loop in my application [My image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hGNxs.png)

In the image I have provided you can see two activities with one button each. When button 1 is pressed it takes you to the second activity and when button two is pressed it takes you to activity one which is perfect. The problem is that if I was to continuously press these buttons to navigate between the two then a large selection of activities would build up like a line and when pressing the back button you would automatically navigate through all of the open activities.

1. My question is do I implement an onDestroy method and if so how would go about it?
2. Can I override the back button to take me directly back to activity one and no further?

Comment: `android:noHistory="true"` --- In the Manifest. Beware of implications though, read up on the docs.

Comment: Well in your second activity don't use Intent just finish(); your activity, it will close your second activity and resumes the first activity

Comment: Rakshit could you give an example? this is what I'm currently using.    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ContactUsMainActivity.class));

Comment: @james : When you click your first button you are using intent to go to Second Activity, so when you click on the Second button in your second activity just use finish(); . It will close your Second Activity and Resumes your First activity

Comment: You can simply call `finish()` after you pass intent for next activity

Answer (score 1):

Implement the intents as shown below:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Home.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

when new activity is opened previous activity will be closed.

Answer (score 1):

> My question is do I implement an onDestroy method and if so how would go about it?

You can call finish() whenever you pass to next activity

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Activity1.this, Activity2.class);
startActivity(intent);
finish();

Intent intent = new Intent(Activity2.this, Activity1.class);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

> Can I override the back button to take me directly back to activity
>   one and no further?

In `Activity2`, you can call `onBackPressed` in `onClick` like

```
    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               onBackPressed();
            }
        });
}
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
     // do what ever you want before you back to previous activity
     super.onBackPressed();
     // call super.onBackPressed(); or finish();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let say you are going to second activity using following

```
 button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
             Intent to_second=new Intent(FirstActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
             startActivity(to_second);
        }
    });
```

Now in your Second Activity do following

```
button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
             finish();
            }
        });
```

button2 will finish your Second Activity and Resumes your First activity again and you can again click on the button1 to open Second activity and the circle continues.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can make both activities `launchMode="singleInstance"` in your `AndroidManifest`. You can although send something through `onNewIntent()` calls.

Don't call `super.onBackPressed()`, because it causes `finish()` to be called, just start another activity.

You can use this solution, if you don't need to recreate activities, otherwise use CLEAR_TOP & etc